# Error while reading gzip files using python

Tags: python, gzip

I'm trying to open and read .gz file, and keep getting the error -

> zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back

The file that I'm trying to read were created line by line, using this code

```
with gzip.open(output_path + out_fn, 'a') as fout:
      json_str = json.dumps(json.loads(data)) + "\n"
      json_bytes = json_str.encode('utf-8')
      fout.write(json_bytes)
```

which ran after each time new streaming data came (to 'data' var).

This is the scrip that I used to read the .gz file -

```
with gzip.open(file_path) as f:
    new_lines = []
    for line in f:
        new_l = line.decode('utf-8')
        new_l = json.loads(new_l)
        new_lines.append(new_l)
```

The error is raised from the 'for' line, after successfully reading some lines, so there might be something wrong with specific lines.

I'll be ok with only skipping those problematic lines if possible, or of course fixing the entire file.

---

Edit:

I've uploaded the .gz file here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/wp34maf8n8wb5ur/tweets.gz?dl=0

I couldn't find a smaller example sorry.

Comment: I could not reproduce your error (in a Windows machine). If you start with a new compressed file, does the error still happens? Do you have some minimal test data that causes the error to provide?

Comment: @nonDucor - example op gave has "a" as file mode opening. If  op would run the script few times, multiple "gzip archives" would be added to a single file, which most likely could lead to the issue .. maybe

Comment: [The gzip format is supposed to handle concatenated files.](https://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/manual/html_node/Advanced-usage.html) I, too, failed to reproduce this, and agree that a minimal and complete example would be interesting.

Comment: Thanks for trying!
I've uploaded the problematic file, sorry for it's size.

Comment: It is possible that you corrupted the file by running your update lines from multiple threads or multiple processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting "invalid distance too far back" because there is an invalid distance that's too far back. Your gzip file is corrupted. Something happened to it between when you created it and when you tried to read it (and uploaded it to dropbox).

Your gzip file is sequence of *many* small gzip members, each of which can be decompressed individually. Upon encountering the error, you can search for the start of the next gzip member and try decompressing from there. Each gzip member starts with the bytes `1f 8b 08`. If you run into another error, then try again from there with another search and decompress.

Having done that, it looks like on the order of 10% of the gzip members in that file are bad.

Comment: Thanks!
Once I split the file using the header you said, I was able to skip the bad gzips.

Comment: You should take some care. Those three bytes could, just by chance, appear in the middle of compressed data. In fact, for a file this large that's pretty much guaranteed to happen several times. If you're just splitting every time you see those three bytes, you may break gzip members that are otherwise perfectly fine.